# Wrong php notice

Tags: php, apache, memory

I am running php application on multiple servers one of the server start going bad. 
e.g. See Below notice
Undefined index: Oroperties in "xyz.php" file on line 123.

Actual index on line 123 is "Properties" where as PHP start interpreting it as "Oroperties"
first letter get changed.  I have observed similar pattern for one function name.

Restarting apache gracefully resolves the problem .

My best guess is memory get corrupted on high load but what is culprit I am not able to pin point. Any help or clue will be appreciated.

Comment: This might have good luck on `serverfault`, too

Comment: What's your setup ? Any opcode cache ?

Comment: Could you share the exact line of code? For science?

Comment: Hi,
We are using apc cache to cache objects and memcache used to cache the data.
Following is line of code.
$tempPfCode[] = $val['Properties']['value_'.$this->pubchannel];

Comment: That is a pickle. I would assume that if you get memory corruptions on this level, it would also be a lot more random than this, and less consistent. Can't think of anything that would change the value of one byte consistently.

So perhaps it is APC. Make sure you are on the latest version and note that PHP 5.5 has a new opcode cache altogether

Comment: Thank you Evet. We are using APC 3.1.9 & PHP 5.3.15. We will upgrade APC first and php we will move to Opcode Cache.